# AR model driven by non-iid input

Tags: time-series, arima, model, iid

I want to use an AR(1) model to describe a time series, but I know that the driving variable at each timestep is not iid. The autocorrelation function of the time series suggests an AR(1) process, but is there a way for me to modify the statistical formulation of an AR(1) process in the case where the driving noise violates the iid assumption?

Comment: What kind of non-iid'nes do you have?

Comment: "Driving variable" -- is that an econometrics term? (I'm coming from stats)

Comment: @Jon, that must be the shocks/innovations/errors that are "driving" the system.

Comment: @RichardHardy, thanks for your comments.  The non-iid'ness is a series of inputs - these tend to be a series of impulses. So the input is always positive, and is most likely correlated in time.  Does that help?

Comment: Why don't you post your data ?

Comment: @IrishStat. Thanks for your question.  I don't have any actual data for the input - but I have a time series of a system response.  The autocovariance structure of the response suggests an AR(1) model.  However, I know that the inputs to the system are not iid, and so I want to know how (if at all) I need to modify the AR model to account for this.

Comment: Please post your data in an excel format detailing the frequency of observations.

Comment: Let me guess: if hydrologist posts his data, the answer by IrishStat will be a complete model for the data created using commercial software. The actual question that is being asked will not be answered in there, and the attention will be drawn away from the actual question. That happens regularly and offers an example of a rather surprising phenomenon: posting data need not always be helpful.

Comment: What do you think about my answer? Since you have not accepted it, do you need further clarification?

Answer (score 1):

Technically it should be possible to define a model like
$$
y_t = \beta_0 + \beta_1 y_{t-1} + u_t
$$
(which would be AR(1) if $u_t$ were i.i.d.) with $u_t$ being, e.g., ARIMA(p,d,q) or some other process. You would simply add an equation for $u_t$ right under the equation for $y_t$ when you formulate the model. This could be implemented in R using

```
arima(y[-1], order=c(p,d,q), xreg=cbind(y[-length(y)]))
```

Perhaps the model has a simpler representation that could be found by playing with the lag polynomials for $y_t$ and $u_t$, but the current one should do the job, too (i.e. its parameters could be estimated and it could be used for forecasting).